# jquery ajax and submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, submenu

Hello everybody first time i post here, excuse my english for mistakes!

well i am quite new in jquery and java but i learn day after day and i found a webpage very nice

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/03/09/animated-content-menu/

On the demo of this tutorial webpage, you have a menu and when you click on it it desepear  and a specific submenu appaear depend of the element of the menu you selected.

> 1. My first question is: i know how to let the menu visible when i click on one the element but i don't know how to close a submenu by clicking on another element of the menu. In default demo you have a cross you click to remove the submenu and let visible the menu again. I hope this explanation makes sense.
> 2. The second question is how when you land on the main page, show directly a submenu of one element of the menu because on default demo it land with empty content and just background.

Thanks you very much for every answers.
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for your first question they have markup like:

```
<ul id='menu'>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <div>Content goes here</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <div>Content goes here</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And you would have script like:

```
var anchors = $("#menu a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var clicked = this;
    $(this).siblings('div').show();
    anchors.filter(function(index) {
        return this !== clicked;
    }).siblings('div').hide();
});
```

To show something as soon as you land on the page you would do:

```
$("#menu a:first").click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i try to use your solution for displaying something when the page is fully load. Of course i change the id with the proper one ;-) but it don't seem to work. When the page is loading it don't do anything

Comment: Did you wrap this javascript in $(document).ready(function() { //code goes here }) ? I am not sure what your problem is exactly.

Comment: yes i wrap it with what you mentionned, in fact when u visit the demo page, you have the main menu appears, but i want for example the submenu of Appetizers appears directly when the page is finish to load, like a click simulation on Appetizers, this webpage use prototype.js maybe it's make some probs. Anyway thanks for your time John

Comment: Yeah, there could be some conflicts between prototype and jquery. I have never used prototype so I am not sure.

Comment: ok thank u anyway for the tips i will try to investigate more, i begin in jquery so it's quite hard. Don't know why the click don't work when the page is load